# Ember: Serialize arbitrary hash key names

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my `model` I have an arbitrary hash (`DS.attr()`) whose properties are returned dasherized. Example,

```
{
  'lorem-ipsum': 'Some value',
  'dolor-sit': 'Some value'
}
```

I want the key names to be camelCased. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can write your [custom transform](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/release/classes/DS.Transform).

In `ember-cli` use `ember g transform my-custom-transform`.

Then you write `DS.attr('my-custom-transform')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) use a custom serializer for your data requests.

e.g.:

```
$ ember g serializer application
```

creates:

```
app/serializers/application.js
```

If the attributes returned by your server use a different convention you can use the serializer's keyForAttribute() method to convert an attribute name in your model to a key in your JSON payload.

In your case, if your backend returned attributes that are dasherized instead of camelCased you could override the keyForAttribute method like this.

```
// app/serializers/application.js

import { camelize } from '@ember/string';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  keyForAttribute(attr) {
    return camelize(attr);
  }
});
```

You can find more information aboud this at [Ember Models Reference](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.1.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_attribute-names)